# Can't modify views after rotation with fragment

Tags: android, rotation, fragment

I've a main layout with 1 fragments. The fragment java class binds some views and when I start the first time all view are correctly populated from onActivityCreate event.
When I rotate the phone I have all retained data in the fragment but I can't update any views from onActivityCreate event o other events...
Is there any example for rotation with fragment that contains views ?

As requested I add the code where I add the fragment

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/questionListFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.sp1d3r.itil.itiltester.QuestionListFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/testFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        class="com.sp1d3r.itil.itiltester.Test_Fragment"  />
</LinearLayout>
```

in this case I've two fragments but the problem is that I can't update any Test_Fragment views after device rotation

here the code of fragment class

```html
public class Test_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private final static String TAG = "ITIL_TESTER";

    private final static int SIXTY_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 60;
    private final static int ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    private final static int MIN_FLIP_DISTANCE = 100;
    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private TextView question_TV;
    private Context mContext;
    private DBHelper itildb;
    private TextView answer1_RB, answer2_RB, answer3_RB, answer4_RB;
    private LinearLayout ll;
    private ScrollView scrollViewQA;
    private ImageButton next_IB, prev_IB;
    private ITIL_Test test;
    private int idButtonPrev;
    private FileToDB fdb;
    private Test_Fragment tFragment;
    private int maxQuestionNo;
    private SwipeGestureListener gestureListener;
    private TextView timerView;
    private long mills;
    private boolean loadFlag = false;

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);


        mLog("Pass from onCreate");
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedState);
        mLog("Pass from onActivityCreated");


        if (!loadFlag) {

            initLayout();
            itildb = new DBHelper(mContext);


            maxQuestionNo = 40;
            //Create a new test with 40 questions and 60 minutes
            test = new ITIL_Test(this, maxQuestionNo, 60, itildb);

            test.asynchLoadfromDB();

            test.setCurrentQuestionNo(1);
            loadFlag = true;

        } else {

            mLog("set the question!!!");
            showQuestion(test.getCurrentQuestionNo());
            mLog("Question no." + test.getCurrentQuestionNo());
        }
   
        mLog("FRAGMENT ID:"+String.valueOf(getId()));

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":onDestroyView()");
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":onDetach()");
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":onPause()");

        super.onPause();
        countDownTimer.cancel();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
 
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":onResume()");


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":onStart()");
 

        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, getClass().getSimpleName() + ":onStop()");
        super.onStop();
    }

 

private void showQuestion(int no) {
    //set question sentences
    question_TV.setText(test.getQuestionSentenceByQNo(no));

    //set answer sentences
    answer1_RB.setText(test.getAnswerListByQNo(no).get(0).getASentence());
    answer2_RB.setText(test.getAnswerListByQNo(no).get(1).getASentence());
    answer3_RB.setText(test.getAnswerListByQNo(no).get(2).getASentence());
    answer4_RB.setText(test.getAnswerListByQNo(no).get(3).getASentence());

..
....

}
```

After I rotate the device I can see into the  logs "set the question!!!" and "Question no." correctly but the views fail to update through showQuestion(test.getCurrentQuestionNo()); method that works at first run instead.

Comment: Please add the code showing where you add the fragment to the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the mistake made in my fragment.
It is in onCreateView. When there are same views in fragments first is necessary to create a view inflating correspondent layout and after use it.
So this is the wrong way:

```html
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);
    }
```

and this is the right way:

```html
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);

        // initialize here some view 
        return v;
    }
```